# Loading and Saving LinkedLists from/to file

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I'm working on a stock control program. I have a StockItem object for each item available, and a StockLinkedList to store multiple different StockItem objects. I'm wondering if there is a way to save my current LinkedList to file, and load it in again using object streams. I attempted to play around with FileOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

The barebones of my StockLinkedList class at the moment is as follow:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.*;

public class StockLinkedList implements StockList {

    LinkedList<StockItem> stockItemList;

    public StockLinkedList(){
        stockItemList = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void loadStockData(String filename){
        try {
            FileOutputStream stockFile = new FileOutputStream(filename + ".dat");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        }
    }

    public void saveStockData(){
        ObjectOutputStream save = ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
        save.writeObject(objectToSave);
        save.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Serialize it to JSON and back doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: Maybe you're misunderstanding the way to use the streams. When you want to read information, you should use InputStream and to write, you should use OutputStream.

Comment: @MarceloTataje Yeah, I though so too. I am learning all of this via google, and found that some people were using FileOutputStream to load in files, which confused me but I tried it none the less

Comment: @Divers Is JSON not JS only? This is a standard Java console app

Comment: What format do you need to display your info? Text file, JSON, XML, serialize to a file?

Comment: by the way, you can use JSON to handle your information as a data transfer format, it does not matter if you are not in a Javascript environment. I mean, preferrable using it on a JS application, but you can use it in this app as well.

Comment: @MarceloTataje Not really using it to display anything at the moment, just want save the current state of the LinkedList and load back in from file. I have an interface set up to display the info via console, it's just a base level application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanna save the state of your object in a file (serialize to a file) I would suggest you to implement the following methods:

```
/**
 * This method will write your stock information into a file
 * @param path Is the target path in your file system
 * @param list Is the list you want to save
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
 */
public void writeStockInfo(String path, LinkedList<StockItem> list) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    //1. Point to your file using File
    File file =  new File(path);
    //2. Then use OOS but to serialize into a file you should use FileOutputStream inside the invocation
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    //3. Just write the object to a file using the method "writeObject"
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(list);
    //4. Close the streams
    objectOutputStream.close();
}

/**
 * This method will read the information of the stock in a file
 * @param path Is the file from which you will read the info
 * @return
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
 */
public LinkedList<StockItem> readStockInfo(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    LinkedList<StockItem> infoList = new LinkedList<StockItem>();
    //1. Point to your file (the one you want to read)
    File fileToRead = new File(path);
    //2. Use OIS to read the information from a file using FileInputStream
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileToRead));
    //3. Just read the object and cast to make sure you obtain the right object
    infoList = (LinkedList<StockItem>) objectInputStream.readObject();
    //4. Close the stream
    objectInputStream.close();
    return infoList;
}
```

Just make sure your "StockItem" class is implementing Serializable interface.

Btw: I edited it because I forgot to close the streams (shame on me!)

Hope this helps you.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to go with Json serialization. Kick-off example with [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library usage.

```
    public static List<Weight> importDataFromFile(String path) {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        String s = FileHelper.readTextFromFile(path); (just read text from file)
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Weight>>() {
        }.getType();
        return g.fromJson(s, listType);
    }

    public static int exportDataToFile(String path, List<Weight> weights) {
       Gson g = new Gson();
       FileHelper.writeTextToFile(path, g.toJson(weights));
    }
```

Weight object in my sample is simple POJO. e.g.:

```
public class Weight {
    private long date;
    private int value;
    private String unit;
    //geters setters
}
```